# Canvas popup with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a canvas drawing in my page. I'm finding some difficulties. I want a drawing canvas popup when I clicked on the button. I have canvas code with me, but I couldn't make it popup when I clicked on the button.

```
<canvas id="pad" width="1366″ height="271″>
<p>Not Supported</p>
</canvas>
<style>
html, body {
    width:  100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
}
</style>
<script>
var isMobile;
    function isTouchDevice() {
       var el = document.createElement('div');
       el.setAttribute('ongesturestart', 'return;');
       return typeof el.ongesturestart === "function";
    }

    isMobile = isTouchDevice();

    if(window.addEventListener) {
        window.addEventListener('load', function () {
            var canvas, context, draw;

            // Touch Events handlers
            draw = {
                started: false,
                start: function(event) {

                    context.beginPath();
                    if (isMobile){
                        context.moveTo(
                            event.targetTouches[0].pageX,
                            event.targetTouches[0].pageY
                        );
                    }else{
                        context.moveTo(
                            event.pageX - this.offsetLeft, 
                            event.pageY - this.offsetTop
                        );
                    }
                    this.started = true;

                },
                move: function(event) {

                    if (this.started) {
                        if(isMobile){
                            context.lineTo(
                                event.targetTouches[0].pageX,
                                event.targetTouches[0].pageY
                            );
                        }else{

                            context.lineTo(
                                event.pageX - this.offsetLeft, 
                                event.pageY - this.offsetTop
                            );
                        }
                        context.stroke();
                    }

                },
                end: function(event) {
                    this.started = false;
                }
            };

            // Canvas & Context
            canvas = document.getElementById('pad');
            context = canvas.getContext('2d');

            // Full Window Size Canvas
            context.canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
            context.canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

            // Events
            canvas.addEventListener('touchstart', draw.start, false);
            canvas.addEventListener('touchend', draw.end, false);
            canvas.addEventListener('touchmove', draw.move, false);
            canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', draw.start, false);
            canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', draw.move, false);
            canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', draw.end, false);

        });     // Disable Page Move
        document.body.addEventListener('touchmove',function(event){
          event.preventDefault();
        },false);
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: what do you mean by popup? like it's invisible and make it visible ?

Comment: Without showing us the code you are using we can't help you.

Comment: by clicking on the button, that canvas should be visible and invisible when click on the close button.

Comment: i updated the question with canvas code.